# How to sort a Map by enum attribute of an object

Tags: java, enums

If have two enum for a poker game:

```
public enum Best{ ROYAL_FLUSH, STRAIGHT_FLUSH, FOUR_OF_A_KIND, FULL_HOUSE ,
       FLUSH, STRAIGHT, THREE_OF_KIND, TWO_PAIRS, PAIR, HIGHEST};

public enum Rank{ ACE, KING, QUEEN, JACK, TEN, NINE, HEIGHT, SEVEN, SIX, FIX, FOR,
THREE, TWO}
```

And I need to make a list of `Combinaison`, the Class `Combinaison` being with two attributes, `best` for best hand and `highest` for highest card:

```
public class Combinaison {

    private Best best;
    private Card.Ranks highest;
}
```

So I make a Map and some combinaison:

```
 Map<String, Combinaison> combinaisonList = new HashMap<String, Combinaison>();
Combinaison comb1 = new Combinaison (FLUSH, SIX);
Combinaison comb2 = new Combinaison (STRAIGHT, HEIGHT);
combinaisonList.put("Player1", comb1);
combinaisonList.put("Player2", comb2);
```

The map contains : < Player1, comb1 ; Player2, comb2>

How do I sort it so that it first sort the card by `Best` and if there is tie, it sort it by `Rank`?

Comment: You don't. A `HashMap` isn't ordered at all, let alone by an attribute of its values.

Answer (score 2):

This Comparator will sort the way you want.

```
    public class CombinaisonComparator implements Comparator<Combinaison> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Combinaison c1, Combinaison c2) {

            int i = c1.getBest().compareTo(c2.getBest());
        
            if(i == 0) {
                i = c1.getHighest().compareTo(c2.getHighest());
            }

            return i;
        }

    }
```

This is how the Comparator can be used.

```
    Combinaison comb1 = new Combinaison(Best.FLUSH, Rank.SIX);
    Combinaison comb2 = new Combinaison(Best.STRAIGHT, Rank.HEIGHT);
    
    List<Combinaison> combos = new ArrayList<>();
    combos.add(comb1);
    combos.add(comb2);

    Collections.sort(combos, new CombinaisonComparator());
```

You can see the example I wrote and run it here.
https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/dLn

You should consider adding a `player` field to your `Combinaison` class so you can use a List instead of a Map and still know which player goes with which Combinaison.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a comparator to compare the values as you need and then collect in a `LinkedHashMap` which preserves the order. Note that `HashMap` doesn't preserve the order.

Assuming you have `getBest()`, `getHighest()` in your class, code looks like:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Combinaison>> comp = 
       (e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().getBest().compareTo(e2.getValue().getBest()) == 0 ? 
             e1.getValue().getHighest().compareTo(e2.getValue().getHighest()):
             e1.getValue().getBest().compareTo(e2.getValue().getBest());

Map<String, Combinaison> sortedMap = 
       combinaisonList.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(comp)
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry<String, Combinaison>::getKey,
                   Map.Entry<String, Combinaison>::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement `Comoarable` in `Combinaison`:

```java
public class Combinaison implements Comparable<Combinaison>{

    private Best best;
    private Card.Ranks highest;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Combinaison other){
        int ret=best.compareTo(other.getBest());
        if(ret==0){
            ret=highest.compareTo(other.getHighest());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This uses the fact that enumerations implement `Comparable`.

This allows to compare and sort `Combinaison`s.

In order to keep the order in a `Map`, you could use `LinkedHashMap`:

```java
combinaisonList.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((a,b)->a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue,(a,b)->throw new AssertionError("Same key cannot exist multiple times in the same Map."),LinkedHashMap::new));
```

This gets a `Stream` over all entries, sorts it by its values (using your `Comparator`) and collects it to a `LinkedHashMap` (keeping the ordering).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List` instead of a `Map`, create an object Player which will contain name and the "Combination", and then sort it by fields.

```
class Player {
private String name;
private Combination combination;

public Player(String name, Combination combination) {
    this.name = name;
    this.combination = combination;
}

public Combination getCombination() {
    return combination;
}
```

}

And then use it like this:

```
    List<Player> combinationList = new ArrayList<>();
    Combination comb1 = new Combination(Best.FULL_HOUSE, Rank.SIX);
    Combination comb2 = new Combination(Best.FULL_HOUSE, Rank.ACE);

    combinationList.add(new Player("Player1", comb1));
    combinationList.add(new Player("Player2", comb2));

    Comparator<Player> compareBest = Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getCombination().getBest());
    Comparator<Player> compareHighest = Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getCombination().getHighest());
    combinationList.sort(compareBest.thenComparing(compareHighest));
```